# Pass values to action=URL in a HTML form and get the response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I've an e-store, one of my payment methods is (Mobile Recharge Cards)

Recently I was doing every thing myself, i receive the recharge number and recharge it on my phone, then mark the order as 'complete' if the number is correct and if not i just ignore it

Now it's too hard to do it, so I searched the web for some solution and i find a one

This webpage:
http://www.stc.com.sa/wps/wcm/connect/english/individual/mobile/prepaid/Charging-Sawa

has a form that send the card balance directly into my phone, and it shows whither the card number is correct or not

So, I'm trying to create an api from this form to recharge the card directly into my phone

I checked this link and i found that it's call another webpage (https://my.stc.com.sa/wps/portal/sawaRecharge/en?cardtype=sawacard&customertype=individual) and include it inside an iframe

I don't want anyone to create the API, all I need is someone who can help me to takeout the (Form Action URL), their system is keep changing the (action="https://my.stc.com.sa/wps/portal/!ut/p/b1/.........") URL each time I refresh the webpage, also they don't even include the Action URL direct in the form tag like this:

```
<form name="sawaRechargeContestForm" method="post" 
action"/wps/portal/!ut/p/b1/......../">
..............................
</form>
```

BUT, they coded it like this:

First they create an A tag and then include the Action URL of the form, which keep changing every time the page is refreshed:

```
<a id="wpf_action_ref_3UISawaRechargeSawaPublicUI15d621bb54d174580_1" 
href="/wps/portal/!ut/p/b1/......../" style="display:none"></a>
```

Then they call the form and define it with (_f) variable

```
_f = document.forms['rechargePublicSawaPageForm'];
```

Then they add the Action URL from the previous (A tag)

```
_f.action = document.getElementById('wpf_action_ref_2UISawaRechargeSawaPublicUI15d621bb54d174580_1').href;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not clear what you are asking or what your problem is.